# Ggplot with label only returns NULL instead of plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, scatter-plot, ggplotly

I have the following problem: I want to add labels to my points in a scatterplot created with ggplot2 and ggplotly. I have read several posts here how to do that with `geom_text()`. However, I always get a `NULL` return if I want to print my plot. Unfortunately, I cannot post my exact data as it is confidential. However, my data frame in which all values to plot are stored in is generally structured in the following way: I have a `xvar` column with characters which represents my x-variable. I have a numeric column `yvar` for the y-axis. Then I have a column `category` which I use to group the data and get similar colours for my points in the plot. And I have a column `pLabel` which contains numeric values which I want to use as labels in the plot.

I coded it in the following way (given the described data frame `df`):

```
pl1 <- ggplotly(ggplot(df,aes(x=xvar,y=yvar,text = paste("sqrt(z):", df$pLabel))) + geom_point(aes(colour=df$category))) 

pl1 <- pl1 + geom_text(aes(label = df$pLabel), hjust = -0.05,vjust = 0.05) 

print(pl1)
```

If I just print pl1 using only the first line of code, it plots everything without the labels. However, it returns `NULL` if I run all three lines of code. How do I need to adjust this that I get my plot and not just a `NULL` return in the console? Thanks!

Comment: You can add layers to a ggplot, but once you convert it to a plotly object with ggplotly it won't work with that syntax. Add the geom_text before you call `ggplotly`.

Comment: Great thanks! Works fine now. Don't know why I didn't try that - such an easy solution.